# Drupal Static HTML content not rendering

Tags: theming

Hoping all is well.. 
I have developed a personal theme and enabled it in a drupal installation. However static html doesn't show up at all.

I have used wysiwyg with ckeditor and enabled full html and still nothing shows up after saving. This happens with nodes and blocks. Only Plain text works and of course that doesn't implement html.

This problem's just began with this project. I have tried to create a fresh website and the problem prevails. I have even tried enabling garland (one of the default drupal themes) and i am still facing the same problem.

Has anyone faced a problem like this before?

Comment: did you inspect that the page using firebug? is actually content showing there, and not displaying because of some css issue?  did you check that?

Comment: On the "fresh website," did you also enable WYSIWYG/CKEditor? I'd try leaving those disabled to just reduce the number of things that might be going wrong - and WYSIWYG can sure make things go wrong…

Comment: @ARUN firebug shows no content displayed just as no content is displayed on the node/block. When i try to edit the node/block, the content is actually there.

Comment: @GarrettAlbright i have actually disabled the editors (uninstalled it as well) to try and narrow the problem down. I am still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it worked out after Upgrading Mysql (from 5.1.. to 5.5..) had php (5.4.17) now its 5.4.22 (guess there's no big difference there..). Thought i'd put it here incase anyone runs into such a weird problem in the future.

Thanks everyone for trying.. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

make sure your Full HTML settings are as shown.
As you see that there is no HTML, there is a strong probability that second option "Display any HTML as plain text" is enabled.

Comment: My settings are like they appear above. Still facing the same problem. Thanks though

Comment: Can you please check how is the data stored in Database. Is it saved with HTML or not ? If HTML is saved, then it is problem with the rendering of the content.

Comment: I have checked and the data is saved as HTML in the database.